# Artin Algebra, 10.3.7

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

$R$ will denote a commutative unitary ring.

> (3.4) Proposition. Substitution Principle: Let $\varphi: R \to R'$ be
> a ring homomoprhism. Then given elements $\alpha_1,$...$,\alpha_n \in
> R'$ there is a unique homomorphism $\phi: R[x_1,...,x_n] \to R'$ from
> the polynomial ring in $n$ variables to $R'$ which agrees with
> $\varphi$ on constant polynomials and which sends $x_i \to \alpha_i$
> for $i = 1,$...$,n$.

The author then says that the Substitution Principle is an efficient way to prove that various constructions of polynomial rings are equivalent, like $R[x,y] \cong R[x][y]$.

> (3.7) Corollary. There is a unique isomorphism $R[x,y] \to R[x][y]$
> which is the identity on $R$ and which sends the variables to
> themselves.
>
> Proof. Consider the inclusion map $\varphi : R \to R[x][y]$. The
> Substitution Principle tells us that there is a unique homomorphism
> $\phi: R[x,y] \to R[x][y]$ which extends this map and sends the
> variables $x,y$ wherever we like. **So we can send the variables to
> themselves.** (...)

This sounds like non-sense. The substitution principle as stated sends the variables to elements of a ring, not to "variables". My first thought is that maybe we could extend the codomain ring with transcendental elements to act like the variables, but then it'd have to be the image of some element of $R$ which also doesn't seem to make sense. And this section is before ring extensions anyway. Is this proof incorrect or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the author's proof.

The "variables" in question are just the elements $x,y$ in the respective rings.

The rings $R[x,y]$ and $R[x][y]$ both have elements named $x,y$.

When the author says

  "send the variables to themselves"

the intended meaning is

  "send the elements named
  $x,y$
  in the ring
  $R[x,y]$
  to the correspondingly named elements in the ring
  $R[x][y]$
  "

the possibility of which follows immediately from the Substitution Principle.

Finally, to show that the homomorphism is an isomorphism, simply verify that the homomorphism is surjective and has kernel $0$.